# Adding a column to the results that would show sequential numbers grouped based on year

Tags: oracle, group-by, sequential

These SQL are able to add a column that has incrementing numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, etc.)

```
select year, quarter, uploaddate, wagecount, SUM(1) 
OVER (ORDER BY year, quarter, uploaddate) as SequentialNumbers from SAMPLE_DATA
order by year, quarter, uploaddate
```

or

```
select your_query.*, rownum
  from (select year, quarter, uploaddate, wagecount 
          from SAMPLE_DATA) your_query
```

Result look like this

| Year | Quarter | UploadDate | WageCount | SequentialNumbers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | 01-JAN-21 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021 | 1 | 02-JAN-21 | 2 | 2 |
| 2021 | 1 | 03-JAN-21 | 1 | 3 |
| 2021 | 1 | 04-JAN-21 | 5 | 4 |

Is there anyway to take the next bold step of making **each year** have its own sequential numbers. In other words results would ultimately look like this

something like this

| Year | Quarter | UploadDate | WageCount | SequentialNumbers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 1 | 01-JAN-21 | 2 | 1 |
| 2019 | 1 | 02-JAN-21 | 2 | 2 |
| 2019 | 1 | 03-JAN-21 | 1 | 3 |
| 2019 | 1 | 04-JAN-21 | 5 | 4 |
| 2020 | 1 | 01-JAN-20 | 2 | 1 |
| 2020 | 1 | 02-JAN-20 | 2 | 2 |
| 2020 | 1 | 03-JAN-20 | 1 | 3 |
| 2020 | 1 | 04-JAN-20 | 5 | 4 |
| 2021 | 1 | 01-JAN-21 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021 | 1 | 02-JAN-21 | 2 | 2 |
| 2021 | 1 | 03-JAN-21 | 1 | 3 |
| 2021 | 1 | 04-JAN-21 | 5 | 4 |

Sample data is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE_DATA (
    YEAR VARCHAR2(4) NULL,
    QUARTER NUMBER(1,0) NULL,
    UPLOADDATE DATE NULL,
    WAGECOUNT NUMBER(10,0) NULL
);

Insert into SAMPLE_DATA (YEAR,QUARTER,UPLOADDATE,WAGECOUNT) values ('2019','1',to_date('27-MAR-19','DD-MON-RR'),5);
Insert into SAMPLE_DATA (YEAR,QUARTER,UPLOADDATE,WAGECOUNT) values ('2019','1',to_date('28-MAR-19','DD-MON-RR'),8493);
Insert into SAMPLE_DATA (YEAR,QUARTER,UPLOADDATE,WAGECOUNT) values ('2019','1',to_date('29-MAR-19','DD-MON-RR'),15070);
Insert into SAMPLE_DATA (YEAR,QUARTER,UPLOADDATE,WAGECOUNT) values ('2019','1',to_date('30-MAR-19','DD-MON-RR'),1244);
Insert into SAMPLE_DATA (YEAR,QUARTER,UPLOADDATE,WAGECOUNT) values ('2020','1',to_date('03-JAN-20','DD-MON-RR'),0);
Insert into SAMPLE_DATA (YEAR,QUARTER,UPLOADDATE,WAGECOUNT) values ('2020','1',to_date('05-JAN-20','DD-MON-RR'),2);
Insert into SAMPLE_DATA (YEAR,QUARTER,UPLOADDATE,WAGECOUNT) values ('2020','1',to_date('06-JAN-20','DD-MON-RR'),3);
Insert into SAMPLE_DATA (YEAR,QUARTER,UPLOADDATE,WAGECOUNT) values ('2020','1',to_date('07-JAN-20','DD-MON-RR'),6);
Insert into SAMPLE_DATA (YEAR,QUARTER,UPLOADDATE,WAGECOUNT) values ('2021','2',to_date('21-APR-21','DD-MON-RR'),59);
Insert into SAMPLE_DATA (YEAR,QUARTER,UPLOADDATE,WAGECOUNT) values ('2021','2',to_date('22-APR-21','DD-MON-RR'),10);
Insert into SAMPLE_DATA (YEAR,QUARTER,UPLOADDATE,WAGECOUNT) values ('2021','2',to_date('23-APR-21','DD-MON-RR'),16);
Insert into SAMPLE_DATA (YEAR,QUARTER,UPLOADDATE,WAGECOUNT) values ('2021','2',to_date('24-APR-21','DD-MON-RR'),1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `row_number` analytic function:

```sql
select year, quarter, uploaddate, wagecount, 
       row_number()
         OVER (partition by year
               ORDER BY quarter, uploaddate) as SequentialNumbers 
from SAMPLE_DATA
order by year, quarter, uploaddate;
```

Results:

```sql
YEAR    QUARTER UPLOADDATE           WAGECOUNT SEQUENTIALNUMBERS
---- ---------- ------------------- ---------- -----------------
2019          1 2019-03-27 00:00:00          5                 1
2019          1 2019-03-28 00:00:00       8493                 2
2019          1 2019-03-29 00:00:00      15070                 3
2019          1 2019-03-30 00:00:00       1244                 4
2020          1 2020-01-03 00:00:00          0                 1
2020          1 2020-01-05 00:00:00          2                 2
2020          1 2020-01-06 00:00:00          3                 3
2020          1 2020-01-07 00:00:00          6                 4
2021          2 2021-04-21 00:00:00         59                 1
2021          2 2021-04-22 00:00:00         10                 2
2021          2 2021-04-23 00:00:00         16                 3
2021          2 2021-04-24 00:00:00          1                 4
```